# SharePoint custom Sharing button

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I need a share functionality in sharepoint page using my custom share button. The custom share button is present in each row of list item. List is rendered using RESTAPIs with the help of script editor web part in the page.

For share functionality I have used below code

```
function SharePage() {
    EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharingDialog',
        function() {
            DisplaySharingDialog(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, _spPageContextInfo.pageListId, _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId.toString());
        }
    );
}
```

But using this I can share only the page, not the list and list items. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach should work, however `_spPageContextInfo.pageListId` and  `_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId` may be emtpy. I *think* they are only available in item-details or edit pages...

You'd need the "right" URLs for your idea.