# sharebutton / sharelink code

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

I want to create a sharebutton within the O365 sharepoint online (classic envrionment).  I have tried to duplicate the function from the top bar with no succuess

Within each page I would like the user to have a button to allow them to share with other team users

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSOM and call **DisplaySharingDialog** function.

Demo:
The following script is used to add a link to share the current site in SharePoint Online:

```
<a onclick='javascript:DisplayShare();'>share</a>
<script>
    function DisplayShare() {
        EnsureScriptFunc("sharing.js", "DisplaySharingDialog", function() {
            DisplaySharingDialog(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Refer to:

[SharePoint custom Sharing button](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220633/sharepoint-custom-sharing-button/220641)

[Assign "Share" functionality to a custom button](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/286f5cef-f154-4cea-b777-3b399f6b41fb/assign-share-functionality-to-a-custom-button?forum=sharepointdevelopment)